# Can this Question be posted to SO?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a question at SU - https://superuser.com/questions/847133/which-ipads-is-currently-ideal-for-ios-development - and it was put on hold. I've edited the question many times, but SO mods are still at a stalemate regarding it. Some suggested that it was more suitable for SO.

Can the mods here have a look at tell me if I can post it at SO?

**EDIT:**

A screenshot has been included for users with less than 10k rep on SU:

[image: q]

Comment: That is far too opinion based to be on-topic for SO.

Comment: Which one - this question or the one I linked too?

Comment: Your question on SuperUser is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Its also a recommendation question (off-topic here), and is only *marginally* related to programming. For instance, asking what computer you need to build to program in windows would also be off-topic here.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too and hence posted it at SU. On the other hand, experienced developers can offer good insights ...

Comment: And they closed it with the equivalent of our recommendation reason; your question was explicitly off-topic. Sounds like there may not be an SE site appropriate for your question.

Comment: For your answer to be answerable, you would need to provide objective criteria by which one can evaluate which iPad would best fit your needs.

Comment: @ikegami - But isn't that what I am ignorant about and asking clarification on?

Comment: @Sam, I hope not. We have no way of knowing the criteria that defines the best choice for you unless you tell us.

Comment: @ikegami  - I meant yes, isn't it clear from the question that I was asking about that - the "objective criteria" to evaluate how to purchase an iPad for ios development?

Comment: @Sam, Not, it's not clear that you are asking for a list of possible criteria. In fact, the post clearly asks something entirely different ("*which iPad*")

Comment: Are there any SU 10k users or mods who can include a screenshot of the question in question?

Comment: @Mooseman: Here you go - http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=261kcok&s=8 - the last revision of the question I did before I gave up.

Comment: You could try asking in chat. I often see that recommendation as an avenue for off-topic opinion-based questions.

Answer (score 12):

No.

The question would be closed as "Primarily Opinion-based". (Super User also has this policy, but the "Product recommendation" reason was more specific.)

Comment: Can't the question be edited in some way to avoid that?

Comment: @Sam Not really.

Comment: Can users offer "opinion" (as answers) on SU?

Comment: @Sam Not really anywhere on the Stack Exchange network unless a site has expressly permitted it (World Building, being an example).